# Как избавиться от лишней таблицы в бд

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_product` varchar(180),
  `creator_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- Внешний ключ
  `rating_product` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
  `url_adress`  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `access` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, -- 0 = public; 1 = private.
  `complet ` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, -- 0 = не завершен; 1 = завершен.
  `display_library` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, -- 0 = не виден в библиотекте, 1 - виден, 0 доступен для с режимом платной подписки
  `ganre_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL, -- Внешний ключ. 
  `categories_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`creator_id`) REFERENCES users(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`ganre_id`) REFERENCES ganres_products(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`categories_id`) REFERENCES categories_products(`id`)
  );
```

Суть: данная таблица хорошо подходит для описания моих сущностный, проблемы возникают только из-за 2 полей. Поле `ganre_id` может быть у одной сущности, при этом у этой же сущности не может быть значения поля `categories_id`, и наоборот, если есть значение у сущности `categories_id` его не может быть у `ganre_id`.

Я вижу следующие решения:

1. Использовать Default 1 в полях `categories_id` и `ganre_id`. В соответствующих таблицах создать занчение с id = 1, которые бы соответствовало значению отсутствия.
2. Создать отдельнуя таблицу `products-2`  для `categories_id` , а `ganre_id` оставить в текущей. Но это ведь не найс, из - за 2 полей 2 почти идентичные таблицы.

Товарищи, как быть? Может быть есть другие решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чем определяется наличие или отсутствие у сущности того или иного атрибута? Можно ли на основании значений остальных полей таблицы однозначно определить, что у сущности есть, а чего нет?

Если да - решением может быть вульгарный набор триггеров BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE, зачищающий значение неподходящего атрибута. Типа

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_attr
BEFORE INSERT 
ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF функция_проверяющая_необходимость_genre THEN
    SET NEW.genre_id := NULL;
ELSE
    SET NEW.categories_id := NULL;
ENDIF;
END;
```

Если нет - то триггер тоже поможет, но следует решить, какой из двух грохать, если в исходных данных есть оба.

Если запись с ошибочными атрибутами надо не корректировать, а отказать во вставке/корректировке - ну генерите соотв. SIGNAL в триггере, операция отменится по ошибке.

И в любом случае - решить, что делать, если у записи нет ни одного из атрибутов.

Answer (score 0):

Объявить эти поля как NULL. NULL и использовать как нет значения. В частности, NULL является корректным отсутствием значения и при обработке внешнего ключа.

А вот `check constraint` mysql не умеет, поэтому правило что значение может иметь только или `categories_id` или `ganre_id` придётся аккуратно проверять на приложении или городить триггеры на `before insert` и `before update`.

PS: что такое `ganre`? Есть слово `genre` - жанр.

Comment: я думал таккое использование null по умолчанию антипаттерн, то есть это нормальная практика в мой ситуации? Да, ошибся - хотел написать genre

Comment: @АлександрРезов *я думал такое использование null по умолчанию антипаттерн*. Nullable поле ссылки для необязательного атрибута - обычное дело.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вынес такую связь в отдельную таблицу с полем enum для указания типа связи. В основной таблице оставил бы, например, поле атрибут, а в enum перечислил бы допустимые атрибуты. Так всегда можно расширить число полей которые подвержены уникальности подобно вашей в вопросе.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  ..
  attr_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (attr_id) REFERENCES attributes(attr_id)
)

CREATE TABLE attributes (
  attr_id INT not null prim key,
  attr_type ENUM('genre', 'category'),
  attr_value CHAR(64) not null
)
```

Да, хранить значения атрибутов придётся в одной таблице. Будет солянка. Но они на то и в одной т.к. похожи по смыслу. Зато можно добавить новое значение в enum и сразу получить уникальность уже по трём полям, и более.

Comment: *Я бы вынес такую связь в отдельную таблицу с полем enum для указания типа связи.* А FK ты при этом как намерен организовывать? которые последние 2 в показанном DDL.

Comment: @Akina в моём примере есть FK

Comment: Где FK на таблицы `ganres_products` и `categories_products`? В упор не вижу... а они были.

Comment: @Akina это потому что вы не внимательно читаете текст самого ответа

Comment: Ваше решение отключает проверку целостности данных средствами SQL-сервера на основе внешних ключей. И от внимательности чтения ответа этот факт никак не изменяется.

Comment: @Akina нет, не отключает. все внешние ключи на местах. просто две таблицы (категории и жанры) превращается в одну (атрибуты - о чём я и написал в ответе). и к этой таблице внешний ключ всё ещё есть.